# How to copy a select amount of columns with all rows that have a specific number in column A

Tags: vba, excel, copy-paste, autofilter

I'm trying to copy columns A to E from one sheet that has certain values in Column F.
For example I want to copy rows A:E that have a 'X' in column F and paste them to another sheet.

I have a code that can copy and paste All rows that have an 'X' but not sure what to change to be able to only copy rows A to E.

Here is my code.

```
With ws.Result.Range ("A1:F" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row
.AutoFilter Field := 6, Criteria1 := wsResult.Range("C1") ' checks row F to 
see  whether the number in cell C1 matches any in row F

If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Columns(1)>1 Then .
Offset(1). Resize (.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy 
Destination:= Main.Range("A22")
```

Comment: The code you posted...are you sure it's right? `ws.result.Range`? And the lines are broken? No way to encode

Comment: add a column count to the resize: `Resize (.Rows.Count - 1,5)`  This should exclude column F

Comment: Perfect Scott! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewritten as,

```
With ws.Result.Range ("A1:F" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row)
    ' checks row F to see  whether the number in cell C1 matches any in row F
    .AutoFilter Field := 6, Criteria1 := wsResult.Range("C1") 
    with .resize(.rows.count-1, 5).offset(1, 0)
        If cbool(Application.Subtotal(103, .Cells)) Then
            .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:= Main.Range("A22") 
        end if
    end with
end with
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Scott Craner for the answer. Correct code is below.
"add a column count to the resize: Resize (.Rows.Count - 1,5) This should exclude column F –"

```
With ws.Result.Range ("A1:F" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row
.AutoFilter Field := 6, Criteria1 := wsResult.Range("C1") ' checks row F to 
see  whether the number in cell C1 matches any in row F

If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Columns(1)>1 Then .
Offset(1). Resize (.Rows.Count - 1,5).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy 
Destination:= Main.Range("A22")
```